flutter connecting two windows physical machine devices for development debugging
Two windows physical machine devices
I want to use one for development and the other for debugging
I think it should be like connecting an android device, connecting two windows and then launching the app to the other device for debugging and development by flutter run -d windows2
I'm envisioning doing this by launching two, because I'm working on a LAN clipboard sharing tool, so I need to do this, and I'll have to launch two to facilitate debugging
flutter run -d windows1
flutter run -d windows2

